Events not showing in Test Events in Meta Analytics using Conversation API with Ruby on Rails
I’m working on a Ruby on Rails app and integrating Meta’s Conversation API. Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Generated an access token.
Created the event body.
Validated the event body using the Meta Payload Helper.
Sent the events to analytics via the API. POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/#{PIXEL_ID}/events"

However, I don’t see any events appearing in the Test Events section of Meta Analytics.

Here is my body
body = {
  data: [
    {
      event_name: "Purchase",
      event_time: DateTime.current.to_i,
      action_source: "other",
      original_event_data: {
        event_name: "Purchase",
        event_time: DateTime.current.to_i
      },
      user_data: {
        external_id: "12345"
      },
      value: 100.00,
      custom_data: {
        currency: "USD",
        order_id: "67890",
        price: 100.00,
        revenue: 90.00,
        item_id: "11111",
        item_name: "Title",
        purchase_type: "purchase_type",
        platform: "Web",
        discount: 10.00,
        quantity: 1
      }
    }
  ].to_json,
  access_token: "access_token"
}


After a few tries, I determined that my events weren't coming because the action_source was other. I changed it to web and it started receiving events.
